# How to formulate index match with if statements?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem in my formula regarding on "EQUAL/MATCH" value using if and index match. I have two sheets, "Targets(database)", and "STUDENTS(input)". Example from sheet "STUDENTS" if I input 80% in Performance1, it will look to sheet Target(table) the Performance1 having equal to 80% and multiply it to the multiplier 10%. See table and sample below

[TARGET(table range)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udacC.png)

[STUDENTS(correct answer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMtxp.png)

**FORMULA**

```
=IF(
  C7<Targets!$C7,
  Targets!$C$5*$B7,
  IFERROR(
    INDEX(
      Targets!$C$5:$H$5,1,
      MATCH(STUDENTS!C7,Targets!$C7:$H7,0)
    )*$B7,
    INDEX(
      Targets!$C$5:$H$5,1,
      MATCH(STUDENTS!C7,Targets!$C7:$H7,1)
    )*$B7
) )
```

Now the problem here is that when I input an "**EQUAL/MATCH**" value, example Performance1 80% the answer must be 3%(10%*30%) but it gives me 2.70%(9%*30%). See below incorrect answer

[STUDENTS(incorrect answer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwoej.png)

What can I try next?

Comment: Separate each part of your formula and check if each is giving the result you expect.

Comment: Yes I already did that but when I'm trying to input an equal value it gives me incorrect answer.

Comment: seems you have pasted wrong picture as same picture is in your "table"-link and "database"-link. please include the columns and rows in your screenshot, so it's easier to read the formula.

Comment: @tnavidi - Hi Sir thanks for your reply! Already edited my post

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to recreate your error, when i put 80% in performance1 i get 3%, like in your first screenshot.